# Laravel Query Builder on (column1 + column2 + ..)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

I've some problem to translate this raw query to Laravel Query Builder:

```
    SELECT
    (x.ans_277 + x.ans_278 + x.ans_279 + x.ans_280) as jml, `a`.*
FROM
    `rawdata` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `answer` AS `x` ON `x`.`mhs` = `a`.`id`
WHERE
    `jalur` = 1
AND `is_lest` = 'Y'
AND `x`.`ans_173` NOT IN (8,10)
AND `x`.`ans_182` NOT IN (17,11)
AND (x.ans_277 + x.ans_278 + x.ans_279 + x.ans_280) < 1000001
ORDER BY
    `final_time` ASC
```

i've been trying use this:

```
$query->where('(x.ans_277 + x.ans_278 + x.ans_279 + x.ans_280)','<',1000001);
```

but it's not working.

Comment: you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whereRaw()`:

```
$query->whereRaw('(x.ans_277 + x.ans_278 + x.ans_279 + x.ans_280) < 1000001');
```

Comment: add query builder code snippet to your question, add expected and actual result or error message if you have any error.

Comment: @Panahbiru any reply here? :)